# dplyr rowwise mutate without hardcoding names

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to do something like this

```
df <- iris %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(new_var = sum(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width))
```

Except I want to do it without typing the variable names, e.g.

```
names_to_add <- c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")
df <- iris %>%
  rowwise %>%
[some function that uses names_to_add]
```

I attempted a few things e.g.

```
df <- iris %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(new_var = sum(sapply(names_to_add, get, envir = as.environment(.))))
```

but still can't figure it out. I'll take an answer that plays around with lazyeval or something that's simpler. Note that the `sum` function here is just a placeholder and my actual function is much more complex, although it returns one value per row. I'd also rather not use `data.table`

Comment: Easy in base R - `iris$new_var <- rowSums(iris[names_to_add])`

Answer (score 0):

You should check out all the functions that end with `_` in `dplyr`. Example `mutate_`, `summarise_` etc.

```
names_to_add <- ("sum(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)")   

df <- iris %>%
  rowwise %>% mutate_(names_to_add)
```

---

**Edit**

The results of the code:

```
df <- iris %>%
 rowwise %>% mutate(new_var = sum(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width))

names_to_add <- ("sum(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)")   

df2 <- iris %>%
    rowwise %>% mutate_(new_var = names_to_add)

identical(df, df2)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score -1):

**Edit**

I edited the answer and it solves the problem. I wonder why it was donwvoted.

We use SE (standard evaluation), passing a string as an input inside 'mutate_'. More info: `vignette("nse","dplyr")`

```
x <- "Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width"
df <- mutate_(iris, x)
head(df)
```

Output:

```
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa                        8.6
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa                        7.9
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa                        7.9
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa                        7.7
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa                        8.6
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa                        9.3
```

Comment: @organic agave I edited my answer. I get the same output that your first lines of code. Did you try it?

Comment: Hi @organic agave if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.